# google map with specific directions like public transportation and driving route

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am making an application that can get the directions from one point to another. just like in the google map website there's a choices where the route for driving, walking, public transports and cycling by typing the street or location of the two points.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsService

Answer (score 0):

You want to use direction API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/